# UIButton title appears with dots when set programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I set the title of the `UIButton` in the xib, it works fine, but when I set the same text programatically to the title of the button it is trimmed.

`BUY THIS FILM FOR 20.00$` -> `BUY THIS FI...FOR 20.00$`

Comment: did you set a custom font or size on the UIButton if you did it in the xib file?

Comment: I didn't change neither the font, nor the size. Just the text of the titleLabel

Comment: are you sure you did it like this: [_button setTitle:@"BUY THIS FILM FOR 20.00$" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: I did it like this:  _subscribeButton.titleLabel.text =...
I'll try your way

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama it worked. Put it as an answer, I'll check it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this way:

```
[_button setTitle:@"BUY THIS FILM FOR 20.00$" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

What is displayed in interface builder when you edit the xib is not guaranteed to look exactly like when it is loaded on the simulator or device.

Solution: just make your Button a little bit wider.

Also, double check that the text is **exactly** the same as in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
btnObj.titlelabel.minimumFontSize = 8.0; // or some more adequate size
btnObj.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```